# Variable name in Angularjs filter

Tags: angularjs

I'm using a search box(input) for filtering the table result. Currently it filters regarding StudentName column, but it needs to be dynamic.

Lets say:

```
filter :{'RollNo' :test}
filter :{'Dept' :test}
```

Program in short:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="test">

<table>
    <tr ng-repeat="x in names |filter :{'StudentName' :test}"></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow below method - 
To Search different things you need to use different input fields otherwise you got to create your custom filter with your type of requirements

```
<label>Any: <input ng-model="search.$"></label> <br>
<label>Name only <input ng-model="search.name"></label><br>
<label>RollNo only <input ng-model="search.RollNo"></label><br>

<table>
  <tr ng-repeat="x in names | filter:search">
    <td>{{x.name}}</td>
    <td>{{x.RollNo}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**EDIT**

Here is custom filter for your case:

```
.filter('TableFilter', function(){
    return function(dataArray, type, filtervalue) {
        if (!dataArray) {
            return;
        }else{
            if(type === 'Name'){
                return dataArray.filter(function(item){
                    var term = item.name === filtervalue;
                    return term;
                });
            }else if(status === 'RollNo'){
                return dataArray.filter(function(item){
                    var term = item.RollNo === filtervalue;
                    return term;
                });
            }
        }
    }
});

<tr ng-repeat="x in names | TableFilter : dropDownvalue : test">
```

Comment: All in one Input is my problem .I have dropdown to choose from

Comment: what is there all things in your dropdown. How do you find what are you searching for. i.e. name, rollno ?

Comment: User can able to select one of the list("name","RollNo") in dropdown then I will collect the user clicked value from dropdown and then I need to put the value in angularjs filter,  exactly in StudentName place in code   (<tr ng-repeat="x in names |filter :{'StudentName' :test}"></tr>)

Comment: confusing. Are you saying you have one dropdown for type of fields you want to search like name, roll and other input field for real value for them?

Comment: in that case see EDIT